# Disabling CORS using js fetch

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

I've looked into it and my syntax looks correct but I can't figure out what is going wrong.

If I don't include the `fetch` `options` params, everything works fine except that CORS is on, which is what I do not want.

After adding the `options` with `mode: 'no-cors'` in the request, I am now getting this error with all requested images:

> `image-cropper-modal.js:73 GET data: net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

I have already tried looking at [MDN's Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/.

Here is my code:

```js
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors'
};

fetch(url, options).then(response => response.blob())
   .then(blob => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const type = blob.type;
        const [image, dataUrl] = [new Image(), reader.result];
        image.src = dataUrl;
        const [width, height] = [image.width, image.height];
        const {minWidth, minHeight} = props.opt;
        const isWithinBounds = (width >= minWidth) && (height >= minHeight);
        callback({
          dataUrl,
          height,
          minHeight,
          minWidth,
          width
        });
   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(blob) 
});
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server side?
In dev mode, I use to put this to avoid CORS

response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

Comment: FYI - in your second link, about no-cors it states **Of course, you can't read the content of the response** which makes it pretty clear that your code would fail to read the response (even if cors headers are present, I believe)

Answer (score 26):

Using the `no-cors` option will *not* give you a readable response:

> `no-cors` — Prevents the method from being anything other than `HEAD`, `GET` or `POST`. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not add or override any headers except for these. **In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response.** This ensures that ServiceWorkers do not affect the semantics of the Web and prevents security and privacy issues arising from leaking data across domains. *([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode), emphasis mine)*

In other words, if you want to make a request from JavaScript, you need to have CORS enabled. If you can't set up CORS support on the server yourself, the only way around this is to proxy your request through a server makes non-CORS requests on your behalf (either by using up your own server, or by using a third-party service such as [crossorigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/) or [cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/), or any of a bunch of other similar services).

For context, the `no-cors` option is available because there are some cases where you may want to make a non-CORS request without having to be able to read the response. For instance, [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) can use this option to intercept (e.g., redirect or cache, but not read or modify) requests made by the browser (like `<img>` tags or HTML pages, not just JavaScript code).

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Anchalee Not one that does not involve the user of proxies; however I have linked to some public CORS proxies in my answer.