# Ajax 'blocked by CORS policy'

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, cors

Like to load https version of a page if its available.  My code is 'blocked by CORS policy'.  Seems stupid that a secure connection should be blocked.  Can I fix this with javascript only without having to add further serverside code? (and without using jquery).

```js
// check if ssl version of the page is available
if (window.location.protocol=="http:") { 
 newurl = "https:"+window.location.href.substr(5);

 // get an ajax object
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) req=new XMLHttpRequest();
 else if (window.ActiveXObject) req=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 else req=false;
 
 // run ajax
 if (req) {
  // setup return function to load page if it was successful
  req.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (req.readyState!=4) return;
   if (req.status==200) location.href=newurl;
  }
  // attempt to open url
  req.open("GET",newurl,true);
  req.send("");
 }
}
```

Comment: https://debugnotes.wordpress.com/2015/06/17/ajax-and-ssl/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030425/disabling-cors-using-js-fetch

Comment: New url to be `"https:"+ window.location.href.substr(6)`

Comment: Apparently making a secured remote AJAX call from an unsecured context should be permissible, but in my testing only unsecure to unsecure, and secure to secure works.

Comment: @user1416526 - what value does your server respond with for the header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://siteB.com/' from origin 'http://siteA.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
GET https://siteB.com/ net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Answer that worked for me was to add this to the website header: 
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteB.com'); // php